# jQuery function: pass callback functions as optional arguments to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I've written the following convenience function to let me easily put jquery UI autocomplete on elements.

```
jQuery.fn.bindAutocomplete = function() {
  $(this).each( function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source')
    });
  });
}
```

I always use the convention of attaching `data-autocomplete-source` to an element so I can call this anywhere just like so:

```
$('input#name').bindAutocomplete();
```

Now, the autocomplete function can take callback functions as optional arguments after the options hash. I almost never need to mess with that, but I've found that in a small number of instances I'd like to pass a success function through. Obviously I can just rewrite the full autocomplete function when I need to pass it callbacks, but I'd rather just rewrite my `bindAutocomplete()` function so it can accept optional callback functions and pass them through to `autocomplete()`.

So, how do you do that?

---

*Update*

I tried this, based on a close but not quite answer below:

```
jQuery.fn.bindAutocomplete = function(callbacks) {
  $(this).each( function(callbacks) {
    options = $.extend({source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source')}, callbacks);
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
  });
}
```

This binds autocomplete correctly whether you pass callbacks in or not, but if you do pass callbacks they don't get called.

Ie: the following triggered autocomplete but not the callback.

```
$('input#name').bindAutocomplete({ select: function(){alert("working");} })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do this if that's what you mean...

```
jQuery.fn.bindAutocomplete = function( opts ) {        
  return this.each(function(){
    opts = $.extend({
      source: $(this).data('autocomplete-source')
    }, opts);
    $(this).autocomplete( opts );
  });
}

$('input#name').bindAutocomplete({
  change: function() { ... },
  close: function() { ... }
});
```

Comment: I had to edit my code a few times but that should work AFAIK but haven't tried.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work in my test. Using your exact code it doesn't bind autocomplete. I tried to modify and will paste into my question, but my attempt didn't work either.

Comment: Aha! Now it works. So, $.extend is just adding the options together to an object that can be passed through?